# Control node/pod affinity of individual pods of statefulset in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I want to control the node affinity of individual pods of a same statefulset. Say, I have a cluster on cloud of 3 nodes and each node belongs to a different zone. My statefulset resource has 6 replicas and needs to follow below constraints.

```
1. Distribute pods such that each node gets 2 replicas always.
2. If one node gets down, the 2 pods running on it should not get rescheduled on other nodes and be in Pending state.
3. When that down node comes up, those 2 pending pods should come back on it.

Is there a way to achieve it?
```

Comment: What happens if you start a fourth worker node?  (This sounds more like a DaemonSet than a StatefulSet.)

Comment: No, no more worker nodes will be added! and its statefulset only

Comment: you requirement to achieve that only using `statefulset`? or implementation may differ?

Comment: @Vitalii Yes, I have to use only ```statefulset```

Comment: @Nish not sure that is achievable

Comment: May be PodTopologySpread can help a bit in this kind of situation.

Comment: @Nish, yes if we are talking about your 1st requirement, then [topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/) is your choice and the first that comes to mind. here question is more how to acheieve 2nd and 3rd. In theory, you can create [custom scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/) that will be based on [Scheduling Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/policies/) and [Scheduler Profiles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/#profiles).